# How do I send string as Springs' @RequestParam using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot

In my backend (Spring controller) I have a method with `@RequestParam String sentence` as request param. I'd like to my a request (post) to this method by sending appropriate parameters.

In AngularJS I wrote:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/wordCount', '?sentence=blah')
```

but backends return the error `Required String parameter 'sentence' is not present"`

Here's my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "wordCount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String count(@RequestParam(value = "sentence") String sentence) {

        //omitted
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't second parameter be an object? e.g. `{sentence: 'blah'}`

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino I have already tried this. Unfortunately, no luck/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `@RequestParam` is for query string params(URL query params). `@RequestBody` is for Post request body.
Now $http.post usage is [mentioned](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) as post(url, data, [config]) where data is Post data which can be captured using `@RequestBody`. But since you need `@RequestParam`, then you need to pass the query string param attached to the url like 
`$http.post('http://localhost:8080/wordCount?sentence=blah',{})`.

Answer (score 0):

URL parameters are set using the `params` property of the `config`:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/wordCount";
var params = { sentence: "blah" };
var config = { params: params };

$http.post(url, data, config);
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)